# Update Razor Partial View from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view that I call from another view with this code `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Fields/Toto.cshtml", totomodel).`

To refresh/update only this partial view, I need to re-call it from javascript (with ajax) with the new data.
but this partial view don't have a controller to make a call like

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Action(......)',
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST'        
    }).done(function (result) {}
```

**How to make a call like `@Html.Partial("")` in javascript ?**

To resolve the problem I rebuild the partial view with string html in javascript. it worked but it's not clean.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What's stopping you from adding an action method to an existing controller or new controller that returns your partial view?

Comment: I want to keep the code on the client side

Comment: Why? Why would you place an artificial restriction on yourself? If doing as I said is the most straightforward way, why would you just say you don't want to do it?

Comment: sorry may be I did not explain all the case

Comment: it's not an artificial restriction, I call the @Html.Partial("~ /Views Fields/1 to x) more than 100 times in a loop to display differents reusables fields (each partial view represent a different type of field), if I add a controller to each partial view, I would have 100 calls for controler in addition to a partial view call. I am not an MVC expert but I guess it's better to call the partial view directly !!!

Comment: Then you need to design this better. Instead of having it be a view partial, perhaps you should use some sort of client side templating engine such as React, Vue, Angular, Handlebars etc that you can loop over different objects and generate HTML for based on a template.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used templates to resolve my problem